# Are these graphs nonisomorphic?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I have got graph $G$ and graph $H$.

[image]

My question is are these graphs isomorphic?

I think no, because in graph $G$ vertex $v_{2}$ has four neighbours:

- $v_{1}$ with degree two
- $v_{8}$ with degree three
- $v_{3}$ with degree four
- $v_{6}$ with degree five

But in graph $H$ vertex $x_{8}$ or $x_{4}$ has four neighbours but with different degrees.

For example $x_{8}$ has neighbours:

- $x_{9}$ with degree two
- $x_{1}$ with degree five
- $x_{4}$ with degree four
- **$x_{7}$ with degree two**

and $x_{4}$ has neighbours:

- $x_{3}$ with degree two
- $x_{1}$ with degree five
- $x_{8}$ with degree four
- **$x_{5}$ with degree two**

Because only $x_{4}$ and $x_{8}$ have degree four, not any one can be relfect to $v_{2}$ and $v_{3}$
So graphs $G$ and $H$ is non-isomorphic.
Is it correct please?

Comment: Yes, it’s correct, though you should complete it by listing the degrees of the neighbors of $x_4$ to show that they also don’t match the degrees of the neighbors of $v_2$. You should also point out that since $x_4$ and $x_8$ are the only vertices of $H$ of degree $4$, they are the only ones that could possibly correspond to $v_2$. (I realize that you understand this, but a complete argument would specify it.)

Comment: Thank you, I try edit my post, I hope that is righ now.

Comment: Yes, that’s fine. Another way to show that they’re not isomorphic: $G$ has two pairs of adjacent vertices of degree $2$ ($v_1,v_7$ and $v_4,v_5$), and $H$ has only one such pair ($x_2,x_3$).

Comment: A similar point of view:  Both graphs $G,H$ have a unique vertex of degree $3$ ($v_8$ and $x_6$ respectively).  In $G$ the neighbors of $v_8$ have degrees five, four, and two.  In $H$ the neighbors of $x_6$ have degrees five, two, and two.